# How can I create a dynamic CSS margin?

Tags: html, css

I could probably do this in PHP, but I would have to include the CSS into my PHP file. So, I have a parent div whose height always varies, and then I have a child div whose `width: 100%; height: 100%;` in that child div, I have text. The problem is, I want to vertically center the text inside the `ChildChild` div.

```
#parentDiv {
width: 200px;
height: PHP generates this;
}
#Child {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
#ChildChild {
margin: how do I do this?
}

<div id="ParentDiv">
<div id="Child">
<div id="ChildChild">
HELLO!
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your text is only going to be one line high, try setting `line-height: 100%;`. Otherwise, maybe try following the [solution outlined here](http://css-tricks.com/2767-vertically-center-multi-lined-text/), which involves using the `display: table-cell;` property to allow the desired use of the `vertical-align: middle;` property.